# Repeat Scramble Function until Output is Different from Input

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have a javascript function which takes a string and scrambles the letters:

```
function scramble(a){
    a=a.split("");
    for(var b=a.length-1;0<b;b--){
        var c=Math.floor(Math.random()*(b+1));d=a[b];a[b]=a[c];a[c]=d;
    }
    return a.join("")
}
```

The problem is, sometimes it outputs the same value as the input. If I unscramble "TREE", it could come out as "TREE".
How can I check before outputting and have the function run again if the output isn't different from the input?

Thanks!
Brendan

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion and call your function again until you know that you're not returning the same string you began with. Side note: your shuffling creates a global variable `d`. Try to use `var` when decalring a new variable.

**EDIT**: As suggested by [user3297291](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297291/user3297291), there should be a check in place to ensure the input is at least 2 characters long and isn't just the same character repeated the entire length of the string. Otherwise, we would be placed in an infinite loop.

```js
function scramble(a){
    if (a.length < 2 || isAllRepeats(a))
      return a;
    var b = a.split("");
    for(var i = b.length - 1; 0 < i; i--){
        var c = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1));
        var d=b[i];b[i]=b[c];b[c]=d;
    }
    var newString = b.join("");
    if (newString === a)
      return scramble(newString);
    return newString;
}

function isAllRepeats(a) {
  var first = a[0];
  var isRepeats = true;
  a.split('').forEach(function(letter) {
    if (letter != first)
      isRepeats = false;
  });
  return isRepeats;
}

console.log(scramble("TREE"))
console.log(scramble("A"))
console.log(scramble("AAAAA"))
```

Comment: If you're using recursion, you might also want to do some checks to determine if there *is* a valid solution. For example, any string of length 1, or containing only 1 character repeated `n` times, will give you an error. You could also specify a retry count/limit to tackle this issue.

Comment: It still fails for `xxx`, but that might be up to the OP to solve. Thanks for the edit, Gavin.

Comment: @user3297291 Added a check for that as well. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion, at the end of your function, check if the output is equal to the input, if it is then `return scramble(a);` if not then `return scrambled_text;`

I also suggest renaming your variables to be more readable, my example return statement above assumes you've renamed variables and whatever the variable your scrambled text is stored in is what I refer to as `scrambled_text`

Answer (score 0):

Recursive approach is what comes to the mind and accordingly you might do as follows; yet probability is something strange and there is always (although very very very rare) the probability to get stuck with the "fish".

```js
function scramble(s){
  function shuffle(a){
    var i = a.length,
        j,
      tmp;
    while (i > 1) {
      j = Math.floor(Math.random()*i--);
      tmp = a[i];
      a[i] = a[j];
      a[j] = tmp;
    }
    return a;
  }
  var t = shuffle([...s]).join("");
  return t === s ? scramble(s) : t;
}

console.log(scramble("fish"))
```